# $f$ be a strictly monotonic continuous function on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a strictly monotonic continuous function defined on $[a,b$ such that $f(a)<a$ and $f(b)>b$. Then there exists exactly one $c\in (a,b)$ duch that $f(c)=c.$

Define $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Clearly, $g$ is a continuous function. $g(a)=f(a)-a<0$ and $g(b)=f(b)-b>0$. So using Intermediate value theorem, we can say that there exists a $c\in (a,b)$ such that $g(c)=0,$ i.e. $f(c)=c$. **But why only one $c$?**

Comment: What is strictly monotonic.

Comment: Yes, that I know. But it is given that $f$ is strictly monotonic which does not imply $g$ is also monotonic.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there can be more than $1$ such $c$.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima:  Intuitively, always increasing.  More precisely, $x \gt y \implies f(x) \gt f(y)$ where the strictly means the greater than sign is not greater than or equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not true.  Let $f(x)=x^3$ on $[-2,2]$  $f(x)=x$ is true for $-1,0,1$

Comment: wait... what? The derivative in $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: @matboy:  That is true, but not a problem.  The definition of strictly monotonic is just $x \gt y \implies f(x) \gt f(y)$, which is true here.  We could even avoid that by taking $f(x)=x^3+\frac 1{100}x$ but finding the two non-zero roots is a little harder.

Comment: @matboy.$ f(x)=x^3$ is strictly monotonic but $g(x)=f(x)-x$ is not. So the equation $g(x)=0$ can have more than one solution, and any solution to $g(x)=0$ is a solution to $f(x)=x.$